# Grouped bar chart with 3 variables (1 on y axis, 1 on x axis, 1 grouped) in r

Tags: r, bar-chart

I'm new to this site and relatively new to R. I need to make a grouped barchart and my issue is that I need my y axis to be the count of observations of a specific variable/column. I have several hundred observations and I need to graph the number of participants who have ever been dependent on alcohol (y-axis) by race and gender. 
I did this:

```
AlcDep_byRG_Table <- table(baseline_Alc_Race_Gender$ALCDEP_3.[baseline_Alc_Race_Gender$ALCDEP_3. >= 3],
                  baseline_Alc_Race_Gender$PRACE[baseline_Alc_Race_Gender$ALCDEP_3. >= 3],
                  baseline_Alc_Race_Gender$PGENDER[baseline_Alc_Race_Gender$ALCDEP_3. >= 3])

m <- colSums(AlcDep_byRD_Table[,,2]) # rows, columns, slice; 2 = second slice, 1, male
f <- colSums(AlcDep_byRD_Table[,,3])
barplot(c(m,f), main = "Alcohol Dependence by Race and Gender", beside = TRUE, xaxt = "n")
```

BUT, I don't know how to make it a grouped/clustered bar chart

I tried using ifelse but then didn't know how to subset it like the above.

Thank you so much for your help!

edit: I tried ggplot

```
ggplot(baseline_Alc_Race_Gender, aes(x=PRACE, y=Alc_Dep, fill = PGENDER)) + 
geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

but the graph has lots of horizontal lines in each bar - anyone know what the mistake could be? Thank you!

Comment: Please edit to include code blocks.

Comment: what is a code block?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I guess you might want to have a look into `ggplot2`

Comment: for some reason my PGENDER and PRACE variables are of the integer  class and as.factor does not work to convert into factors. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

(edited)

```
# create a dataframe like yours
PART_ID<-c(1001,1002,1003,1004,1005)
Alc_Dep<-c(1, 0,1,1,1)
PRACE<-c(1,2,1,3,1)
PGENDER<-c(1,2,2,2,1)
baseline_Alc_Race_Gender <- data.frame(PART_ID,PGENDER,PRACE,Alc_Dep)
baseline_Alc_Race_Gender
# solve the factor issue
baseline_Alc_Race_Gender$PGENDER<-
factor(baseline_Alc_Race_Gender$PGENDER)
baseline_Alc_Race_Gender$PRACE<-factor(baseline_Alc_Race_Gender$PRACE)
baseline_Alc_Race_Gender$Alc_Dep<-factor(baseline_Alc_Race_Gender$Alc_Dep)
# plot it
# do not specify a y!
ggplot(baseline_Alc_Race_Gender, aes(x=PRACE, fill=PGENDER)) + 
   geom_bar(position=position_dodge())
```

Sarah,

It would help immensely if you could share a sample of your data.  But I'll make something up that may be your case.  Three columns race, gender, and a yes or no to alcohol dependence.  This should work no matter how many cases you have.  It may require you to uncomment the install ggplot2 command

```
d <- data.frame(column1=rep(c("race1","race2","race3"), each=4), 
                column2=rep(c("male", "female"), 6), 
                column3=rep(c("yes", "no"), 6))
d
# install.packages("ggplot2") you may need this
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(d, aes(x=column1, fill=column2)) + 
    geom_bar(position=position_dodge())
```

Comment: Example of my data:

    PART ID         PGENDER        PRACE            Alc_Dep
    1001                       1                    1                        1
    1002                        2                    2                        0

I created Alc_Dep by 
   'baseline_Alc_Race_Gender$Alc_Dep <- 
    ifelse(baseline_Alc_Race_Gender$ALCDEP_3. >= 3, 1, 0)'